# How can I pass an object to std::accumulate function?

Tags: c++

I am writing a code as given below. The target of the code is to combine different vectors into a single vector after joining elements from different vectors. The below code is incomplete and I could not find a way to pass the object `s` from `target_fun` to `combine` which is required in the `join` function. The object `s` is not valid in `combine` because it is created in `target_fun`.

```
using Elems = vector<AbsC>;

Elems combine(const Elems & acc, const auto & it) {
  Special p = *it;
  Elems later_element;
  later_Element = this->l.get(p);
  Elems result;
  for (auto a : acc) {
    for (auto n : later_element) {
        result.push_back(a.join(n,s));
    }
  }
  return result;
}

target_fun(Wto& v) {
  Special s = v.node();
  Elems initial_element;
  initial_element = this->m.get(s);
  Elems E = std::accumulate(pre_begin(s), pre_end(s), *initial_element, combine);
}
```

Note that `pre_begin(s)` gives an iterator that can used to get the first vector and `pre_end(s)` gives an iterator to get the last vector and `initial_element` is the initial vector with which I want to join the elements of the `later_element` vectors. Please suggest a code or changes to the above code that can be used to achieve my goal.

Comment: Why is `combine` a separate function? Why not just use a lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of undefined types, which makes this hard to run, but what you will want to do is use a functor rather than a simple function. The functor can store the value as a member which you pass in.  It should look like:

```
struct ElemsCombine {
  Special s;
  Elems operator()(const Elems & acc, const auto & it) const {
    Special p = *it;
    Elems later_element;
    later_Element = this->l.get(p);
    Elems result;
    for (auto a : acc) {
      for (auto n : later_element) {
          result.push_back(a.join(n,s));
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
};

target_fun(Wto& v) {
  Special s = v.node();
  Elems initial_element;
  initial_element = this->m.get(s);
  auto comb = ElemsCombine ();
  comb.s = s;
  Elems E = std::accumulate(pre_begin(s), pre_end(s), *initial_element, comb);
}
```